# Moving from thread-based pipelining to task-based parallelism? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm looking at how to migrate some existing C++ code from thread-based to task-based parallelism, and whether that migration is desirable. Here's my scenario:

Suppose I have some function to execute on an event. Say I have a camera and each time a frame arrives I want to do some heavy processing and save the results. Some of the processing is serial, so if I just process each frame serially in the same thread, I don't get full CPU utilization. Say the frames arrive every 33ms and the processing latency for a frame is close to 100ms.

So in my current implementation I create say 3 threads that process frames and assign each new frame to one of these worker thread in a round-robin. So thread T0 might process frames F0, F3, F6, etc. Now I get full CPU utilization and I don't have to drop frames to maintain real-time rates.

Since the processing requires various big, temporary resources, I can allocate those up-front for each worker thread. So they do not have to be re-allocated for every frame. This strategy of per-thread resources works well for granularity: if they were being allocated per-frame this would take too long, but with many more worker threads we would run out of resources.

I do not see a way to replace this thread-based parallelism with task-based parallelism using standard C++11 or Microsoft's PPL library. If there is a pattern for doing so that could be sketched below, I would be very happy to learn it.

The question is where to store the state - the allocated temporary resources (e.g. GPU memory) - which can be re-used for subsequent frames but must not conflict with the resources for a currently processing frame.

Is it even desirable to migrate to task-based parallelism in this kind of case?

Comment: Could you keep the state in `static thread_local` storage?

Comment: thread_local variables don't work here for tasks. First, the standard states that all thread_local variables must be destroyed when a task completes. Second, even if they persisted, you couldn't guarantee which thread a task may be executed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Here is an example solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using PipelineState = int;
using PipelineStateArg = std::shared_ptr<PipelineState>;
using FrameState = int;
struct Pipeline
{
    PipelineStateArg state;
    concurrency::task<void> task;
};
std::vector<Pipeline> pipelines;

void proc(const FrameState& fs, PipelineState& ps)
{ 
    std::cout << "Process frame " << fs << " in pipeline " << ps << std::endl; 
}

void on_frame(int index)
{
    FrameState frame = index;
    if (index < 2)
    {
        // Start a new pipeline
        auto state = std::make_shared<PipelineState>(index);
        pipelines.push_back({state, concurrency::create_task([=]() 
        { 
            proc(frame, *state); 
        })});
    }
    else
    {
        // Use an existing pipeline
        auto& pipeline = pipelines[index & 1];
        auto state = pipeline.state;
        pipeline.task = pipeline.task.then([=]() 
        { 
            proc(frame, *state); 
        });
    }
}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        on_frame(i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(33));
    }
    for (auto& pipeline : pipelines)
        pipeline.tail.wait();
}
```

Comment: A little explanation of the code would make it more useful, especially for such a complex topic as task-based parallelism.